# python eval error with converting string to dict

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, eval

i am working with python and when i do eval on a string to get a dictionary it shows me the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
the string is received over a socket connection and it contains a dictionary.
i need to get back the original dictionary

Exact error is below

```
File "<string>", line 1 
##here goes my long string received over socket
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea whats going on in this.
I know i can use pickle or json to send data but thats not the req at the moment

Comment: please provide the (minimal) code, where the error happened

Comment: This is my client side code which is sending string 
DataValue = str(data_info)
message = DataValue
sock.send(message.encode())

on server side i receive the data on socket and simply do
dataStr = eval(data)    ## data is received data

Answer (score 2):

First, **never** use `eval` unless you have a very specific use case which requires it: it poses security risks. Instead, use `ast.literal_eval`.

Second, I cannot reproduce your error:

```
import ast

mystr = "{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}"

ast.literal_eval(mystr)        # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
type(ast.literal_eval(mystr))  # dict
```

Comment: i am running same logic on linux and its working fine but when i switch to windows i get the error.
i have seen ast and when i do it works fine but when i run with my code, i get the same old error.

Comment: no i dont get any error with the code you gave me.
i have also tried it before implementing it
when i i try this in my code i get error

Comment: ok, unless you provide your code and full traceback, I can't help further.

Comment: This is my client side code which is sending string DataValue = str(data_info) message = DataValue sock.send(message.encode()) on server side i receive the data on socket and simply do dataStr = eval(data) ## data is received data
in traceback i am just getting **invalid syntax**

Comment: post your code, correctly formatted, as part of your question.